# Problem getting puppet to sync custom fact

Tags: puppet

I am having trouble getting puppet to sync a custom fact. I am using puppet version 0.25.4. The fact is inside a module as described in http://docs.reductivelabs.com/guides/plugins_in_modules.html

If I specify --pluginsync on the command line it does sync correctly, but does not otherwise even though I have pluginsync=true in my puppet.conf.

Is it correct that this command line option and the option in the puppet.conf should have the same behavior?

Comment: As an aside, please consider updating to a more recent version. There's numerous known bugs in 0.25.x whose fixes will never be backported to those versions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Do you have the pluginsync=true in the right section in your puppet.conf (either [main] or [puppetd]) and do you have removed any old puppet**d**.conf?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think 0.25.x supports plugins in modules.  If it does it only supports them when you do not have a plugins mount point defined in fileserver.conf.